# Error "int cannot be dereferenced" en método que debe imprimir los elementos de una matriz pasada como parámetro

Tags: java

Cree un metodo que imprima mis matrices en java para no tener que estar haciéndolo manualmente una y otra vez, paso la matriz como parámetro y debería imprimir.
Será que el error se produce al aplicar .length a las filas de la matriz? La verdad no sé qué esta pasando...

```
public class Matrices {
    public static void a() {
        int m[][]={{1,3,5,7},{2,4,6,8,10},{1,2,4,8,16,32},{0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21}};      
    }
    
    public static void printMatriz(int m[]){
        for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m[i].length; j++){  
              System.out.printf("%02d ",m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
      } 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema en realidad es que estas realizando una operacion usando una array bidimensional pero estas definiendo incorrectamente el que debe recibir, debes usar `m[][]` :

```
  public static void printMatriz(int m[][]){
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j< m[i].length ; j++){  
          System.out.printf("%d ",m[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
  }
```

de esta forma podras imprimir el array sin problema:

```
  int m[][]={{1,3,5,7},{2,4,6,8,10},{1,2,4,8,16,32},{0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21}};      
  printMatriz(m);
```

salida:

```
1 3 5 7 
2 4 6 8 10 
1 2 4 8 16 32 
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21
```